# n Random Points in a Disc, with Constraints on n-1 Points

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Task: select $n$ random points in a disc. The only requirement is that all points have an equal probability of being chosen.

What I have done: 1) selecting a random real in $[0,2\pi)$ for the angle, and 2) selecting a random radius in $[0,1]$ proportional to the square root to ensure the points don't cluster incorrectly. Such a distribution will give an equal chance for every point to be chosen. I'm satisfied.

Now suppose we wish to plot these points for someone to use. The problem is if I pick, say, 20 points, there is a chance that I will select a random point in the disc that is "too close" to a previously chosen point and the little dots on the plot will overlap. So I keep track of points chosen so far and place additional constraints that new points must be a certain distance from an already chosen point.

Clearly if the distance requirement between points is too large than after the first point, no more points can be chosen. But in practice the gap is not very large relative to the number of points required and there's no worry of having some kind of pathological configuration of points with the values used in practice. Consider, for an idea of how much slack we have, that a thousand points would fit on the diameter line and we only need 25 random points total over the whole disc.

My question is:

> Can we say, prior to any points being chosen, that all points have an equal chance of being selected? Does this gap constraint ruin the prior probabilities?

Intuitively I'd say no, the prior probabilities are not ruined, because all points have an equal chance of being the first point, and what happens after that is irrelevant, but I have no background in probability and statistics to rely on to prove this. Against my intuition is the idea that points on the edge become less likely to be chosen due to the gap constraint and that means that points no longer have a uniform chance of being chosen, which was the original requirement.

I know the requirements here are kind of vague but I'm still hoping there's an answer.

Comment: First, the concept of random points on a circle is ambiguous. Have a look here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability). Second, I don't understand why you would want to avoid points from being close. If they are chosen at random then they lie where they lie.

Comment: thedude I don't see why it matters why I want to do it. But it came up because I was trying to select random lattice points in a disc and thought about this approximation to the problem. Also, I am aware of Bertrand's Paradox. Please see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html for instance.

Comment: Existence of repulsion between points, which is what you want to keep them apart, does not necessarily ruin uniform probability. For example, eigenvalues of random Ginibre matrices satisfy both requirements. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_law

Comment: You list two questions, so it is not clear which one you are saying "no" to when you say "I'd say no".

Comment: My hunch is that the distribution is no longer uniform since early points chosen near the edge of the disc eliminate fewer points from future consideration than early points chosen near the center.  This lack of "uniformity" in the effect of early points seems significant, at first glance at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a visual suggestion that the answer is "no", the distribution does not remain uniform.

This is an image of many sets (an overlay, if you will) of 15 points in a disc of radius 150, uniformly, with the condition that no two points in a set are closer than 60.  You can see the concentration toward the edge, suggesting non-uniformity.

[image]

This supports the idea that, since points near the edge eliminate less space for future points, there should be higher concentration of points near the edge.

Not that the picture proves anything, of course.

Comment: This is very interesting and I don't know why I didn't think to run this experiment myself. It suggests to me that there may be a way to correct for the problem by increasing the gap requirement when the circle around a point would have some of its area outside the main disk, but that's outside the scope of my original problem. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Yes, it would be interesting to have the threshold distance vary such that the area occluded by each additional point was always the same.  Cheers!